# Can scrapy submit to an input based on id?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have an Intranet page with multiple input fields, I need Scrapy to run a search using the webpages "search for products" input field, it has an id of "searchBox"

I have been able to lock onto the correct search box using both Scrapy and Beautiful Soup but I am not sure how to pass that data back to Scrapys form submission function correctly.

In Method 1 I have tried to simply pass the results to Scrapys FormRequest.from_response function as an input but it does not work.

**Method 1 - Using Scrapy to find the data**

```
#Search for products
def parse(self, response):

    ##Let's try search using scrapy only
    sel = Selector(response)
    results = sel.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'searchBox')]")
    for result in results:
        print (result.extract())   #Print out what scrapy found
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(results, formdata = {'Item': 'Whirlpool Washing Machine'}) #formdata is the data we are sending
```

**Method 2 - Using Beautiful soup to find the data**

```
#Search for products
def parse(self, response):

    ##Let's try search using Beautiful Soup only
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  
    product_search = []
    product_search.append(soup.find("input", id="searchBox")) 
    print(product_search) #Print what BS found
```

Answer (score 0):

About scrapy variant:

1. You should `yield` request, not `return`.
2. In function `from_response` you should use selector of form as first argument. Now you pass there some input data, as far as I could understand from your code.

Try something like:

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response.css('form'), formdata={'Item': 'Whirlpool Washing Machine'})
```

Just fix form selector in this expression. Also check what else should be used in this request, maybe some headers, cookies, etc.

Comment: I think the input is generated by JavaScript on the fly as it has a different input name=<name> in the browser when I refresh the page in Chrome.

Comment: Only you can see it, since we don't have access to your intranet page. We could only suggest what can be wrong.